# Access 2013 Increment a text ID field in a form

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, ms-access-2013, autonumber

I have created a database from an excel file, one of the columns (PK) is the license number however this is in text format XX/XX/XXXX

When a new record is created I would like the form to auto-populate the license number field with a similar ID containing both text and numbers. This has to be incremented with every new record (only the number part)

This is exactly what I want to achive however I am getting the error shown below; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPz-n5w5YtE

[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, I have experience with VB however I am familiar with other programming languages.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but this seems remarkably simple?  Can you give some examples of what kind of characters this "text number" contains, and how it increments? I'm thinking a simple `DMAX` or `DLAST` is basically all you need.

Comment: looks like you try to work with integer but using a string. is this correct or do I misinterpret the code?

Comment: (Sorry I'm not clicking a YouTube link and you'll find most here also can't be bothered.  It would help if you could summarize to make it easier for others to help you.)

Comment: I managed to find what was causing the error, it was the previous value being different from the new ones in terms or format. I manually inserted a record with the new format and its working, if you have any simpler to suggestions to this I would still appreciate them.

Comment: how was it different in terms of format?  That's a pretty important thing to keep the same!

Comment: Existing License Number: WT/7634/2002 New Format ABC000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your idea is to take a number (8) and convert it to "0008", as in the comment above the error, try like this:

```
strNextNumber = Format(lngNextNumber, "0000")
```

or see the whole code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim strNextNumber As String
    Dim lngNextNumber As Long
    lngNextNumber = 8
    strNextNumber = Format(lngNextNumber, "0000")
    Debug.Print strNextNumber        
End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up using strNextNumber = Format(lngNextNumber, "0000"), its more understandable and fits my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If `lngNextNumber` is greater than 9999, the first argument of the `String`-function will be `-1` or smaller and thus not valid.

So you can either check the value of `lngNextNumber` first.

```
If lngNextNumber < 10000 Then
    strNextNumber = String(4 - Len(CStr(lngNextNumber)), "0") & CStr(lngNextNumber)
Else
    strNextNumber = CStr(lngNextNumber)        
End If
```

Or even simpler, use the `Format`-function, like already mentioned in Vityata's answer.

```
strNextNumber = Format(lngNextNumber, "0000")
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one line is needed:

```
' Old license like "WT/7634/2002".
' New license like "ABC2003"
Me![License Number].Value = Format(Val(Right(DMax("[License Number]", [Licenses]), 4)) + 1, "\A\B\C0000")
```